# How to conditionally add items to a series in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, series

I have the following data frame df1 =

```
Index  Data Positon   Cell

0      220    12      Cell1 
1      256    33      Cell2
2      175    45      Cell2 
3      150    56      Cell1 
4      120    67      Cell2
5      200    77      Cell1 
6      235    79      Cell1 
7      270    83      Cell2 
8      325    87      Cell1 
9      190    91      Cell1 
10     235    95      Cell1
```

I have another dataframe with messages df2 =

```
Index Message Position
0      msg1     31
1      msg2     45
2      release  54 
3      msg2     67
4      msg1     82
```

I want to add a new column to df1 that takes one of the two strings 'value_1' and value_2' as per the following condition

1. Any position in df1 above 0th position in df2(eg.31 in df2),`value = value_1`
2. If the message is msg1, then  `value = value_2` only for rows below position of msg1 i.e `df1['Position'] >= df2['Position'][df2.Message == 'msg1']` where `df['Cell'] = Cell1` . This should continue till we approach `df2.Message = 'Release'`.(checking has to be done)
3. If the message is msg2,then `value = value_2` only for rows below position of msg2 i.e `df1['Position'] >= df2['Position'][df2.Message == 'msg2']` where `df['Cell']= Cell2`.This should continue till we approach `df2.Message = 'Release'`.(checking has to be done)
4. If the message is release, then `value = value_1` till the next message in df2.Message irrespective of df['Cell']
5. If none of 1,2, 3 and 4 is satisfied, `value = value_1`

**In a nutshell**

When a message is detected other than the release message value = value_2 for the cell corresponding to the message ( Cell1 for msg1 and Cell2 for msg2) until a release is detected. Once a release is detected, value = value_1 until next message (msg1 or msg2) is detected.

Tried the following

```
df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
df1 = df1.rename(columns = {'Positon':'Position'}) 
df1 = df1.iloc[:,1:4]
df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
df2 = df2.iloc[:,1:3]
tmp = pd.concat([df2,df1], sort =False).sort_values(['Position']).reset_index(drop = True)
tmp['value'] = 'novalue'
tmp['value'][tmp.Position < df2.Position[0]] = 'value_1'
for i in range(len(tmp)):
    if tmp.Message[i] == 'release':
        tmp.value[i: tmp.Message[i+1:].first_valid_index()] = 'value_1'
    if tmp.Message[i] =='msg1':
        for j in range(len(tmp.index[i+1:])):
            if tmp.Message[j] =='release':
                tmp.value[i:j][tmp.Cell =='Cell1'] = 'value_2'
            else:
                tmp.value[i:][tmp.Cell =='Cell1'] = 'value_2'
    if tmp.Message[i] =='msg2':
        for j in range(len(tmp.index[i+1:])):
            if tmp.Message[j] =='release':
                tmp.value[i:j][tmp.Cell =='Cell2'] = 'value_2'
            else:
                tmp.value[i:][tmp.Cell =='Cell2'] = 'value_2'
result = tmp.loc[~tmp.Cell.isna(),:]
result.value[result.value == 'novalue'] = 'value_1'
```

I am stuck doing this.Basically this code shows values value_2 for position 77 and 79 which should not happen. I am having a hard time figuring out it.

The expected result should be something like this

```
Index  Data Positon   Cell   Value

0      220    12      Cell1  value_1
1      256    33      Cell2  value_1
2      175    45      Cell2  value_2
3      150    56      Cell1  value_1
4      120    67      Cell2  value_2
5      200    77      Cell1  value_1
6      235    79      Cell1  value_1
7      270    83      Cell2  value_2
8      325    87      Cell1  value_2
9      190    91      Cell1  value_2
10     235    95      Cell1  value_2
```

Would be really greatful if someone can help

Comment: I read your logic twice and it still doesn't make much sense to me. What have you tried? why can't you just use a series of `.loc` statements to fufil your conditions?

Comment: becuase that could be hardcoding it to specific order of messages

Comment: update: I have added the code which i believe needs some fixing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the solution !

```
df1 = pd.read_clipboard()
df1 = df1.rename(columns = {'Positon':'Position'}) 
df1 = df1.iloc[:,1:4]
df2 = pd.read_clipboard()
df2 = df2.iloc[:,1:3]
tmp = pd.concat([df2,df1], sort =False).sort_values(['Position']).reset_index(drop = True)
tmp['value'] = 'novalue'
tmp['value'][tmp.Position < df2.Position[0]] = 'value_1'
for i in range(len(tmp)):
    if tmp.Message[i] == 'release':
        tmp.value[i: tmp.Message[i+1:].first_valid_index()] = 'value_1'
    if tmp.Message[i] =='msg1':
        val = tmp.Message[i+1:][tmp.Message == 'release'].first_valid_index()
        tmp.value[i:val][tmp.Cell =='Cell1'] = 'value_2'
    if tmp.Message[i] =='msg2':
        val = tmp.Message[i+1:][tmp.Message == 'release'].first_valid_index()
        tmp.value[i:val][tmp.Cell =='Cell2'] = 'value_2'
result = tmp.loc[~tmp.Cell.isna(),:]
result.value[result.value == 'novalue'] = 'value_1'
```